# Converting a lot of Illustrator files to PNG with transparent background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, transparency, png

I have about 280 Illustrator `.ai` files that I need to convert into `.png` files with a finished size of `500px x 500px`. All of them aren't squared, so those that are, for example rectangular, need to be centered in the image and the background needs to be transparent.

Is there an easier way to do this because I wouldn't like to spend time converting them manually.

Comment: It depends on what operating system you're on. If you're comfortable with using the command line and can install Imagemagick, I recommend that.

Comment: Isn't ImageMagic cross-platform? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you have imagemagick installed, you can run the following command:

```
convert -colorspace RGB \
-background transparent \
-resize 500x500 \
-gravity center \
-extent 500x500 \
yourfile.ai outputfile.png
```

How you iterate over all files in a directory depends on your environment, of course, but something like this should work for bash:

```
for i in *.ai; do convert -colorspace RGB -background transparent -resize 500x500 -gravity center -extent 500x500 "$i" "$i.png"; done
```

Comment: That's a good solution but looking at your code wouldn't all the images have to be square and not rectangular because it will transform all the documents to `500px x 500px`?

Comment: No, the `-resize` switch respects the input image's aspect ratio.  The `-extent` switch then creates the padding, if needed.

Comment: It says `no images defined output.png`. See full error log: http://pastebin.com/mAmhqW6Y

Comment: Hmm. Looks like you're missing Ghostscript, which is required to interpret pdf files. If you do a search for `Imagemagick Postscript delegate failed` you should be able to find a solution.

Comment: I downloaded Ghostscript from [this website](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html). Now I get this error. http://pastebin.com/Xp3SixjK That path is correct. I tried it with forward slashes too, no difference.

Comment: That error leads me to believe that the file was not saved with PDF compatibility. In this case, Imagemagick/ghostscript will not be able to decode the files.  For a windows-based workflow, you may need an Illustrator action to export a PDF compatible file, or try to export a PNG file natively.

Comment: I got an error: `FailedToExecuteCommand "gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Us
ers/JOBADI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-5096najtztCfsCa2%d" "-fC:/Users/JOBADI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-5096K_rJUcXeuO
ld" "-fC:/Users/JOBADI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-5096dd_06nZKQYGS"' (The system cannot find the file specified.
) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/460.
convert: PDFDelegateFailed The system cannot find the file specified`